# MySQL - Distinct "many" values in one-to-many based on results of linked "one" values

Tags: mysql

(I have no idea how to title this question)

I have two tables: `leads` and `calls`

`leads` consists of unique `lead_id` values for each lead and the associated `phone_number` for that lead. There can be many leads with the same phone number.

`calls` consists of `lead_id` values for each call to a lead and the associated `status` of each call. There is no `phone_number` field in the `calls` table.

I have the following query that will extract all phone numbers that do not have any calls in teh `calls` table (regardless of lead_id) that resulted in the `DEAD` status:

```
SELECT DISTINCT phone_number
FROM leads l
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM calls c
    WHERE c.lead_id IN (
        SELECT lead_id
        FROM leads
        WHERE phone_number = l.phone_number
    )
    AND c.status = "DEAD"
 );
```

Now, I am trying to limit the results to only phone numbers that have at least 6 different `lead_id` values in the `calls` table.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the phone number doesn't have any calls, how can you further limit it to numbers with at least 6 different leads in the `calls` table? Or are you replacing "no calls" with "at least 6 different lead_id values"?

Comment: Do you know that your query from sample return lines in leads which do NOT have result DEAD, but have at least one DEAD call doesn't matter how many are successful after that? Just check what will be if the same number have DEAD and SUCCESSS for same lead_id.

Comment: @Barmar In this case, when a phone number has a different lead_id, it is part of a different campaign. I would only want to include phone numbers that were called at least once on each campaign, excluding any phone numbers that were not called or not called on each campaign

Comment: @arheops I am not sure I fully follow. But I did have an error in the code above (leaving out a closing parenthesis). The "DEAD" status would stop the lead from being called again. I am trying to get phone numbers that did not result in a "DEAD" status across 6 campaigns (denoted by the 6 lead_ids)

Answer (score 0):

Join with the `calls` table, then use `COUNT(DISTINCT c.lead_id) >= 6`.

```
SELECT l.phone_number
FROM leads AS l
JOIN calls AS c ON l.lead_id = c.lead_id
WHERE c.status = "DEAD"
GROUP BY l.phone_number
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.lead_id) >= 6
```

Comment: Note, that query will go to they sky with execution time on typical calls/leads tables(both few millions).

Comment: @arheops I realize this. I was trying to figure out how to do the aggregation in a subquery before joining, but I'm not sure how to do that with the `DISTINCT` requirement.

Comment: Sure it is simple.  If you have leads_id in calls table you do not need join at all. I do not know why you guys  trying to join on lead_id just to lookup ... lead_id

Comment: The join is needed because `phone_number` is in `leads`, but `status` is in `calls`.

Comment: WHERE phone_number = l.phone_number

Comment: Phonenumber is in both. That is typical bad dialling core design.

Comment: It's not in both. The question says: **There is no phone_number field in the calls table.**

Comment: oh ok, then your have just count it using subquery. But that is long query anyway. It can be greatly shrinked by counting only on numbers from leads which have at least 6 different leads_id IN LEADS table.

Comment: The problem is that the subquery can't group by phone number when counting distinct lead IDs because there are no phone numbers in the `calls` table.

Comment: Please post your answer showing how to do this better. I can't figure it out myself.

Comment: Yeah, no phone in the calls table.  And counting distinct lead_ids didn't work, as it's counting the lead_ids associated with a single instance of the phone_number. So the only way that works is when HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.lead_id) = 1

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT l.phone_number
FROM (
    select phone_number, count(*), lead_id from leads 
    group by lead_id having count(*)>=6
) AS leads_may_have_6
  JOIN leads l on l.phone_number = leads_may_have_6.phone_number
where 
  not exists 
(select 1 from calls c on c.lead_id =l.lead_id where c.status='DEAD' limit 1)
```

In this example, leads_may_have_6 will be executed for O(N), all other are O(N^2). So shrinking leads to only numbers which already have 6 leads will greatly decrease execution time(I bet most time it will give zero results and will not execute another part at all).

But it is still questionable why you need leads which at least one times have DEAD status doesn't matter what are other attempts.

Select with limit 1 will fetch exactly one row even if you have few thousands attempts for that lead id. Since it select 1, it will just check index and not fetch row at all if you have index on lead_id,status.

Comment: Why do you need `COUNT(*)` in the `SELECT` list?

Comment: I have replaced all of the "final statuses" with the "DEAD" status for simplicity. In reality, I am looking for all the numbers that we have not contacted (any sort of contact would have resulted in a final, or DEAD, status). I had left out a closing parenthesis in my question... not sure if that helps clarify how it produced the initial results

Comment: Interesting about the `SELECT 1` portion. That was new to me. I was actually working with ChatGPT AI to come up with the initial query and that is what it came up with. After checking many of the results, it seemed to be accurate. But I did not check all results

Comment: Count(*) may be needed or not needed by some MySQL forks and version. Some also ask for lead_id in that query. It do not increase query complexity, planner will add it anyway for counting "having".

Comment: Checking expert answers by GPT is a bad idea. ChatGPT will give you "middle software dev" class answers ;) Also sometimes it just give incorrect answer because it found incorrect answers in it's database. You always should compare all variants on your data how it expected to be after year of work(not new tables). Sometimes for your tables simple change can result dramatically performance improvement, but more likely degradation.

Comment: You may or may not need another having(count(*))>6 check after join with calls, but it is not clear from your question if you need it. Anyway second one will be on shrinked set, so will be much faster.

Comment: Well, I stared with GPT but when it couldnt figure this out, I came here... to the experts ;) I am still fairly new to MySQL so it can be tough to absorb the information. My version of MySQL is not liking the "count(*)>=6 group by lead_id" part inside the subquery

Comment: I have no tables and not tested it. If it ask for invalid grouping column, add  lead_id after count(*) in that query. you can test that part independly first.

Comment: ah,yes. Having go after group by. Sorry :) https://www.guru99.com/group-by.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's my understanding from the questions and comments:

**Requirements**

- I am trying to get phone numbers that did not result in a "DEAD" status across 6 campaigns (denoted by the 6 lead_ids)
- I am trying to limit the results to only phone numbers that have at least 6 different lead_id values in the calls table.
- I have replaced all of the "final statuses" with the "DEAD" status for simplicity.
- In reality, I am looking for all the numbers that we have not contacted (any sort of contact would have resulted in a final, or DEAD, status).

**Definitions**

- Dead Lead: a lead_id with an entry in `calls` table `where status='DEAD'`
- Dead Phone Number: a phone number related to 6 or more dead leads (`lead_id`)

**Request**

- Give me all the phone numbers that are not Dead Phone Number

**SQL Query**

```sql
with cte_dead_leads as (
select lead_id 
  from calls 
 where status = 'DEAD')
 group by lead_id),
cte_dead_phone_number as (
select l.phone_number
  from leads l
  join cte_dead_leads d
 using (lead_id)
 group by l.phone_number
having count(*) >= 6)
select l.phone_number
  from leads l
  left
  join cte_dead_phone_number p
 using (phone_number)
 where p.phone_number is null
 group by l.phone_number;
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for this. I have MySQL Workbench and it doesn't appear I can run this query (warning for the starting word "with" and when I run it, it errors when using the `group by` in the sub query) 

Also... from what I can understand of the query, it looks like it would be counting the `lead_id` values in the leads table, instead of the calls table. Since it is possible to have a lead that is loaded into the system but never called, we need to count the `lead_id` instances from the calls table to ensure at least one call was attempted on all 6 campaigns

Comment: @J-- Looks like your MySQL version is less than 8, which doesn't support CTE (Common Table Expression). You can change CTEs into subqueries.